# How to host aurelia in cordova

Tags: cordova, aurelia

is there any way aurelia sample project integrates with Cordova for mobile application? I am new to Cordova and Aurelia am finding it bit difficult, I didn't find any documents for this.

Comment: I dont have any experience with `cordova` , but if you are building mobile apps and it supports modern javascript `ES2015` or higher, yes you should be able to integrate `Aurelia`. Once Aurelia project is bundled up, its nothing but just a javascript library with all the npm packaged merged in to one or two files depending on the settings. You might want to learn how aurelia bootstrapping works and then integrate with your project.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Aurelia framework but you can start with a skeleton for aurelia/cordova project.
There are several on github. ([Example](https://github.com/fragsalat/cordova-aurelia-skeleton))

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Djiggy's answer with Webpack: https://github.com/arjendeblok/aurelia-cordova-skeleton

A few key steps (from the readme):

### Prerequisites

- NodeJS
- Cordova
- Any platform-specific tooling like Android Studio

### Installation

After `npm install`

- `cordova platform add browser` for adding the browser platform to cordova.
- `cordova platform add android` for adding the android platform to cordova.

#### Running in development mode

After `npm build` (with development options):

- `cordova platform run browser` for running the app in the browser.
- `cordova platform run android` for running the app in Android.

#### Running in production mode

After `npm build` (with production options):

- `cordova platform build android`

### Files

In case the github repository disappears

#### `config.xml`

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

#### `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { AureliaPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('app/app.css');
const bundleOutputDir = './www';

module.exports = ({ prod, cordova } = {}) => {
    const isDevBuild = !prod;
    const isCordova = cordova || false;

    return [{
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: ['src', 'node_modules'] // .map(x => path.resolve(x))
        },
        entry: {
            'app': 'aurelia-bootstrapper'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: 'app/app.js'
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: './www'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/i, include: /src/, use: 'ts-loader' },
                { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ?
                        ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] :
                        extractCSS.extract('css-loader?minimize')
                },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ttf|eot)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                { test: /\.woff$/, use: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
                { test: /\.woff2$/, use: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000&mimetype=application/font-woff2" }
            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild), IS_CORDOVA: JSON.stringify(isCordova) }),
            new AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: 'main', dist: 'native-modules' }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'index.ejs',
                minify: prod ? {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true
                } : undefined,
                metadata: {
                   prod, cordova
                }
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]')  // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [])
    }];
};
```

#### `index.ejs`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.cordova) { %>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
<% } %>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>Hello Cordova</title>
    <!-- imported CSS are concatenated and added automatically -->
</head>
<body aurelia-app="main">
    <p>booting...</p>
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.cordova) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<% } %>
    <!-- imported JS bundles are added automatically -->
</body>
</html>
```

#### `src/cordova-events.ts`

```js
export class CordovaEvents {
    waitForDeviceReady(): Promise<boolean> {
        let p = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
                resolve(true);
            }, false);
        });
        return p;
    }
}
```

#### `src/main.ts`

```js
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { CordovaEvents } from './cordova-events';

declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build
declare const IS_CORDOVA: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build
export async function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    if (IS_CORDOVA) {
        const cordova = new CordovaEvents();
        await cordova.waitForDeviceReady();
    }

    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration();

    if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
        aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
    }

    await aurelia.start();

    await aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app'));
}
```